# How to use Essentia in python?

Tags: python, installation

I'm trying to use Essentia in Python, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to install it, I have no clue what's going on in the [install page](http://essentia.upf.edu/documentation/installing.html). Can someone walk me through on how to do it?

Comment: what's the OS you want to use Essentia?

Comment: I'm using windows 7.

Comment: To compile and install Essentia you need to go through the same process as you would go through when installing any self-compiled library. Look for "compile pyd file under windows" and "setup visual studio for python". something like this. Please keep us up to date.

Comment: There is no python binding for windows for this library right now. May be they will be implemented later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There is no python binding for windows for this library right now. May be they will be implemented later. – VMAtm Apr 12 '16 at 19:22

Well, now it's 2018 and there are bindings and the [install page](http://essentia.upf.edu/documentation/installing.html#installing-dependencies-on-linux) looks pretty clear.

There are instructions available for Linux, Mac and compiling from source for Python. Windows seems a bit more iffy and maybe you'd want to try the [dockerized version](https://github.com/MTG/essentia-docker).

Hopefully, now there'll be one less 3-year-old unanswered question in the queue.